# Why is this method to calculate the size of a binary tree not working?

Tags: java, size, binary-tree

ok these binary trees kinda drive me crazy now. I made a method to get the number of nodes in a tree but the result not correct. There is always one node missing. Any ideas? Help would be appreciated since I don't want to become a tree hater :)

```
public int size() {
    if (this == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1 + (right != null ? right.size() : 0) 
                + (left != null ? left.size() : 0);
    }  
}
```

Comment: I think `this` can never be null.  Aside from that, your logic looks correct.  Could you provide an example where this code fails to produce the correct result?

Comment: Could you paste the whole class or at least a constructor and class members?

Comment: Wait a second. Example is coming!

Comment: @user1420042 I believe it would be faster for us and you to paste the whole class containing this method.

Comment: Ok guys, this is kinda embarrassing but please forgive me, its been a long day: I started and created a tree with 6 nodes. Then I ran the project and it always showed 5. However, I just realized that I didn't see that i ALSO was calling a remove() method. So, the upper method is totally fine. But please, don't rate me down. I am so sorry!

Answer (score 0):

First of all the if(this==null) is completely useless and can be removed completely as you are calling a method on this so it is therefore not null. 
Then, can you provide some input and output data as well as expected result ? We can only make assumptions here and the code seems legit.

Comment: indeed... sorry for that. but i need some more rep in order to do that. :)